# VBA: Creating a .txt file containing an array of arrays from a table of data

Tags: arrays, vba

I have a `20x3` table on an excel sheet. Each of the three columns is labeled Date, Price, and Volume. I want to convert this data into a .txt file that contains an array of array, i.e an array containing twenty arrays, where each of the twenty arrays has the format `[Date, price, volume]`. The final array should have the format:

```
[[Date_0, Price_0, Volume_0], . . .,[Date_19, Price_19, Volume_19]].
```

I believe this can be done by writing a loop for each row and printing as an array.

Comment: Is it possible to change the below range argument Macro to output a JSON formatted file?

Answer (score 2):

This is a modification from the above that will take input as a range. It is capable of handling ranges with several areas (multiselection).

```
Public Sub writeRangeToFile(ByRef rng As Range, ByVal path As String)

    Dim fso     As Object, _
        fOut    As Object, _
        rArea   As Range, _
        row     As Integer, _
        col     As Integer

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fOut = fso.CreateTextFile(path, overwrite:=True, Unicode:=False)

    With fOut
        For Each rArea In rng.Areas '' iterate over areas of range, insures all are rects
            fOut.Write "["
            For row = 1 To rArea.Rows.Count Step 1
                .Write IIf(row > 1, ",", "") & "["
                For col = 1 To rArea.Columns.Count Step 1
                    .Write IIf(col > 1, ",", "") & rArea.Cells(row, col).Value
                Next col
                .Write "]"
            Next row
            .Write "]" & vbCrLf
        Next rArea
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

#### Tester

This serves as a general test case, but I think you would want to use a named range in place of `Selection` in your case

```
Sub tester()
   writeRangeToFile Selection, "C:\[your directory]\Test.txt"
End Sub
```

#### Output

Given the selection of

[image: Selection]

the tester function outputs

```
[[B2,C2,D2,E2,F2,G2],[B3,C3,D3,E3,F3,G3],[B4,C4,D4,E4,F4,G4],[B5,C5,D5,E5,F5,G5]]
[[M3,N3,O3,P3,Q3],[M4,N4,O4,P4,Q4],[M5,N5,O5,P5,Q5],[M6,N6,O6,P6,Q6],[M7,N7,O7,P7,Q7],[M8,N8,O8,P8,Q8]]
[[D10,E10,F10,G10,H10,I10,J10],[D11,E11,F11,G11,H11,I11,J11],[D12,E12,F12,G12,H12,I12,J12],[D13,E13,F13,G13,H13,I13,J13],[D14,E14,F14,G14,H14,I14,J14],[D15,E15,F15,G15,H15,I15,J15],[D16,E16,F16,G16,H16,I16,J16]]
[[Q15,R15,S15,T15],[Q16,R16,S16,T16],[Q17,R17,S17,T17],[Q18,R18,S18,T18],[Q19,R19,S19,T19],[Q20,R20,S20,T20]]
```

Comment: I am using the following

writeRangeToFile("MM", "X:\Derivs\Johnny\Test_2.txt")

MM is the named range, however, excel gives a type mismatch error.

Comment: you need to wrap the `"MM"` in a `Range()` call. If the named range is not on the active sheet, you may need to add a worksheet reference. This would look like `Sheets("[your sheet]").Range("MM")`

Comment: Hey Taylor. How would I modify this algorithm to produce a JSON formatted txt. file? The labels would be Date, Price and Volume.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `Open path For Output` call, and then by iterating across the array in both directions.

```
Sub writeArrToFile(ByRef arr() As String, ByVal path As String)

    Dim lOuter As Integer, _
        uOuter As Integer, _
        lInner As Integer, _
        uInner As Integer

    Open path For Output As #1
    Let lOuter = LBound(arr(), 1)
    Let uOuter = UBound(arr(), 1)
    Let lInner = LBound(arr(), 2)
    Let uInner = UBound(arr(), 2)

    Print #1, "[";
    For i = lOuter To uOuter
        Print #1, IIf(i > lOuter, ",", ""); "[";
        For j = lInner To uInner
            Print #1, IIf(j > lInner, ",", ""); arr(i, j);
        Next j
        Print #1, "]";
    Next i
    Print #1, "]";
    Close #1
End Sub
```

or you may achieve this by using a more modern, object oriented approach with

```
Sub writeArrToFile(ByRef arr() As String, ByVal path As String)

    Dim fso     As Object, _
        fOut    As Object, _
        lInner  As Integer, _
        lOuter  As Integer
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fOut = fso.CreateTextFile(path, overwrite:=True, Unicode:=False)

    Let lInner = LBound(arr(), 2)
    Let uInner = UBound(arr(), 2)

    With fOut
        .Write "["
        For i = LBound(arr(), 1) To UBound(arr(), 1) Step 1
            .Write IIf(i > lOuter, ",", "") & "["
            For j = lInner To uInner
                .Write IIf(j > lInner, ",", "") & arr(i, j)
            Next j
            .Write "]"
        Next i
        .Write "]"
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

#### Tester Function

You can test the above with this function. Modify the file path to designate where the subroutine should output.

```
Sub tester()
    Dim arr(0 To 2, 0 To 2) As String

    arr(0, 0) = "a"
    arr(0, 1) = "b"
    arr(0, 2) = "c"
    arr(1, 0) = "d"
    arr(1, 1) = "e"
    arr(1, 2) = "f"
    arr(2, 0) = "g"
    arr(2, 1) = "h"
    arr(2, 2) = "i"

    writeArrToFile arr, "C:\[your directory]\Test.txt"
End Sub
```

#### Output

The above tester function outputs to `"C:\[your directory]\Test.txt"`

```
[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]
```

Comment: Thanks. I have got his working. Many thanks. How would I then apply this tester function to an arbitrary size table? For example if I had an arbietrary table saved as a named range.

Comment: You have the data stored as a range, rather than as a 2D array? That would actually simplify things pretty significantly - give me a second and I'll write up something for you.

Comment: It is a 2D array, it is simply a NxM table. However I have several of these tables in  the one sheet and each is saved as a different named range.

Comment: You should see an additional answer that should handle taking input as a range. Simply change `Selection` in the tester function of that answer to a refrerence to your named range and you should be good